# C# adding console args to WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, console-application

I have a Winforms app,
I am trying to make it so that you can run certain Methods through the command line without displaying the form.

It works with the commandline args, but now it wont open the form with no args..

here is my main

```
static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            if (args[0] == "/s")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Prepping Backup");
                Backup();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Logevent(e.ToString(), "warn", 25);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: Do you have args.Length > 0 where the first arg is not "/s"?

Comment: You could try adding `params` before the `String[] args`

Comment: You're creating your form twice; remove the first `Form1 f = new Form1();`.

Comment: Well, what's the debugger doing when you step through the code?

Comment: @DourHighArch That fixed it! add as an answer so i can accept it!

Comment: Just delete the question; this is a local typo that will not be of use to others.

Comment: It should be `if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "/s") { ... } else { ... }`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

needs to be called before creating first instance of a form. Place it before

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
```

and it will work as expected.

**Edit**
This will create unnecessary instance of Form so another option is to remove 
`Form1 f = new Form1();` entirely

Comment: Please mention the reason before marking it down to not useful. Don't let me miss my learning chance.

Comment: That won't work because he later creates another `new Form` and ignores the first one; he needs to remove `Form1 f = new Form1();` entirely.

Comment: So you mean you can't have 2 instances of Form at the same time?
Until and unless he is planning to use only one instance and getting confused between 2 instances, you are correct.

Comment: You can but he's not using Form `f` at all. He's also creating it before checking arguments which he needs to do first.

Comment: Refer this:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/26960a4c-040a-40b4-baea-15adc275b44c/setcompatibletextrenderingdefault-must-be-called-before-the-first-iwin32window-object-is-created-in?forum=winforms

Comment: I agree he is not using the first instance but the reason its working is the one I mentioned in the answer. We both are right as there is always multiple ways of solving a problem.

Comment: No, your answer is not "right".  If there are arguments, the OP does not want to have a form.  Your solution still needlessly creates one, even if it doesn't show it.  You should fix your answer.